# How could I know the status of the socket connection inside a PrintWriter

Tags: java, sockets, outputstream, printwriter

I use

```
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);

......
output.println(message);
......
```

Since the println function doesn't has return value, it don't throw any exception either.
How could I know the disconnection is cut off?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling [`PrintWriter.checkError()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#checkError()) will tell you if any error has occurred.  It won't specifically tell you which error occurred, but if checkError returns true you can infer that a closed or broken socket was the most likely cause.

If you keep a reference to the socket that you got the input stream from, you can test the status of the socket.

Finally, if you *really* want to know exactly when and why the stream "failed", you could create a wrapper for `OutputStream` that caught `IOException` on the write methods (etc) and rethrew it wrapped in some unchecked exception.

Answer (score 1):

see here , http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html

boolean isClosed() , Returns the closed state of the socket.

boolean isConnected(),  Returns the connection state of the socket.

Comment: those API calls are misleading and can't be used to detect if you are currently really connected, see the code here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/net/Socket.java